# How can I use parameter from rails config file in a coffeescript file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

In my custom rails config file I have "MyApp::Application.config.x.retries = 3"

Is there any way to call it in coffesscript like we do in controller or view with "Rails.configuration.x.retries" ?

Answer (score 1):

If you export those config values (from ruby) to javascript, then you should be able to use them in your coffee script file.

For example, in your layout file (ex: `application.html.erb`) add the following:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  window.retries = <%= MyApp::Application.config.x.retries %>;
<% end %>
```

Then in your coffee script file, you can access it through `window.retries`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped my but I have used another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have used solution presented in RailsCast number [324](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?autoplay=true)

```
<%= content_tag "div", id: "link", data: { url: Rails.configuration.x.link } do %><% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice you found a solution but for the record, another alternative is to embed ruby into your coffeescript file with erb - returning your config data as json.

For example..

*my_app.coffee.erb*

```
class MyApp
    @config = <%= MyApp::Application.configuration.to_json %>
```

Notice I use a coffeescript class which functions more as a namespace. I can call something along the lines of `MyApp.config['x']['retries']`